# preg_match and file_get_contents and æ ø å

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents

I have a question about preg_match, if I try to fetch something like this: Århus er en by i Danmark means Århus is a city in Denmark

```
preg_match( "#<div id=[\"']faktaDiv[\"']>(.*?)</div>#si", $webside, $a2 );

echo $a2;
```

Then the output will be:

> �rhus er en by i Danmark means �rhus is a city in Denmark

How can I fix this? Basically it needs to allow æ ø å.

Comment: @chris85 - how do I do that? Yes, the file is UTF-8

Comment: #<div id=[\"']faktaDiv[\"']>(.*?)</div>#siu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>For the regex approach you need the `u` modifier. For a full list of PHP's modifiers see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php, the `i` and `s` you are currently using are 2 other modifiers.</s>

```
preg_match( "#<div id=[\"']faktaDiv[\"']>(.*?)</div>#siu", $webside, $a2 );
```

It looks like you are parsing HTML though so I'd use the domdocument to parse that string.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div id="faktaDiv">Test Stuff</div>');
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute('id') == 'faktaDiv') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

To pull the `title` you should use a parser like this.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<title>Test Stuff</title>');
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $title;
```

As far as I know there should only be one `title` one a page. If this isn't the case take off the `->item(0)->nodeValue` and loop through the array.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/502432

Comment: The u modifier is deprecated and doesnt work. I'm fetching a website, with file_get_contents, howdo I implement this in your code?

Comment: If I want to get the text between <title></title> from a website, how do I do that with file_get_content?

Comment: OP's problem has nothing to do with the lack of `u` modifier. The pattern string is plain, 7-bit ASCII and the match is found just fine. His problem is he tries to view the output in an encoding different than that of the subject string (wheter it's UTF or not we don't know, but `u` won't magically make it so if it's not).

Comment: @Morten where is the `u` modifier marked as deprecated? If you want title do `$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');`.

Comment: @lafor Yea, magic rarely fixes problems. The `u` modifier tells the `preg_match` to treat the string and pattern as utf8 though. The OP stated +1 hour ago that the file is UTF8, that was my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\X` to match any UTF-8 character (like the dot is used for ansi characters), a specific code point, a range of code points, or an unicode category:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

To answer your question, I'd say that replacing `(.*?)` with `(\X*?)` is enough.

> Matching a single grapheme, whether it's encoded as a single code point, or as multiple code points using combining marks, is easy in Perl, PCRE, PHP, and Ruby 2.0: simply use \X. You can consider \X the Unicode version of the dot. There is one difference, though: \X always matches line break characters, whereas the dot does not match line break characters unless you enable the dot matches newline matching mode.